# Is there a Python to VB .NET conversion tool?

Tags: python, vb.net

I have searched over and over. I can find tools to convert VB code to python but nothing to convert python to VB.NET

Short of that can anyone recommend a solid way to compile a python program into a usable .NET DLL? I have found some stuff on that but they all reference dead links.

Comment: Look into IronPython. It will compile a .NET executable, and then reflect the executable to get the code. The reflector tool (RedGate .Net Reflector) will generate the MSIL needed to generate your source. Requires a little elbow grease but it works just fine.

Comment: I have actually tried that, but I guess I am missing this "MSIL" part of the process (Not sure what that even is). When I use reflector to attempt to decomplile the EXE IronPython creates it seems I just get a bunch of IronPython source code and not the actual python source I used to begin with. Will research MSIL in the meantime.

Answer (score -1):

I use translation:
I know that this is an old question, but I wanted to put this answer to the benefit of those who recently passed through the question, I did not find a direct tool for converting from py to vb.net
But I found a tool to convert from py to c # [Here][1]

And this tool for converting from c # to vb.net is[here][2]

I Hope this is helpful
[1]: https://pythoncsharp.com/
[2]: https://converter.telerik.com/